# NSDateComponents

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have read the following answer from Zaph

[iPhone - Correct way for getting current date and time for a given place / timezone and compare it with another date/time in the same place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362199/iphone-correct-way-for-getting-current-date-and-time-for-a-given-place-timez)

The matter is that i don't understand the following code.

```
NSDate *newDate;
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:~ NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
....
```

I would like to explain to me the reason for using ~ before NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apple demands they are given bitwise. This is the C operator for NOT. Compare [this](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/bit-masks/).