# How to display System Date & Time on UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsdate, uidatepicker

I'm newer in iOS and I tried below code to show the system time on Label. Same I want to display on button.

NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.YY HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
[date_time setText:dateString];
```

//date_time is my Label.
Above code works perfectly but to display on button I used the below code but cudn't work for Button

NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.YY HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
```

[date_time setTitle:dateString forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//date_time is name of Button

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you have made no effort to solve it your self

Comment: No one here is sitting idle to write code for you. Use current time from your device.

Comment: Write code you tried otherwise you'll never learn how to code!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362199/iphone-correct-way-for-getting-current-date-and-time-for-a-given-place-timez set string date&time as title of button :)

Comment: check this out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362199/iphone-correct-way-for-getting-current-date-and-time-for-a-given-place-timez

Comment: I'm newer to objective C and I did effort but I cudnt do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `NSDate *date =  [NSDate alloc] init];`
which get current date.

suppose you have button instance myButton ,
then

```
[myButton setTitle: NSString stringwithformat:@"%@",[date] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

then on button selector initializxe your date picker and on date picker delegate selector mehod set your button title again,
ex,

```
[myButton setTitle:NSString stringwithformat:@"%@",[datepicker.date] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button's title to reflect the system date and time and update with each passing second, you'll need to create an NSTimer that runs once a second and changes the button's title. Take a look at the method scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:

If you want the time to update every second on the second it's a little tricky to start your timer on the second. I can show you some code to do that if you'd like.

Since you want to replace the current time with a user-selected time when the user clicks your button, you would stop the timer when the user selects a new date/time.