# iOS Swift NSDateFormatter gives different output

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

Following piece of code in Swift to generate time stamp of current time, but sometime it gives wrong output like different Year 2016 instead of 2015.

```
    let todaysDate: NSDate = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
    var currentTimeStamp = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(todaysDate)

    print("** Current time stamp: " + currentTimeStamp)
```

I don't understand why does same piece of code give different output?

Comment: ** Current time stamp: 2015-12-31 12:13:18.499
This is the output i got

Comment: I got the right output. It would be more helpful if you tracked down  on which inputs does it give a faulty output.

Comment: @UmaMadhavi Yes, you are right. This is happening some time only

Comment: @UmangKothari I think however it is an issue of timezone settings. Read [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362199/iphone-correct-way-for-getting-current-date-and-time-for-a-given-place-timez). Albertamg's answer.

Comment: @NSNoob Actually I run on iPhone 4s, iPhone 5s and I also ensure that device's current date-time. But facing same problem.

Comment: try using YYYY in place of yyyy.

Comment: @BhavukJain But if 'yyyy' leads to wrong output then It must give different output every time not some time.

Comment: Please show the output of `todaysDate`, `currentTimeStamp `, and `NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().secondsFromGMT` for the problematic cases.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed for me by changing YYYY to yyyy as suggested by BhavukJain in the comments.

From https://8mobile.wordpress.com/2015/05/28/nsdateformatter-nsdate-wrong-year/

y = Year, normally the length specifies the padding, but for two letters it also specifies the maximum length.

Y = Year (in “Week of Year” based calendars), this year designation is used in ISO year-week calendar as defined by ISO 8601, but can be used in non-Gregorian based calendar systems where week date processing is desired. May not always be the same value as calendar year.

Comment: But if 'yyyy' leads to wrong output then It must give different output every time not some time.